# JQuery - How to only target the title tags of text input elements?

Tags: jquery, forms, textinput

At the moment I am using two plug-ins which both look at title tags so they are clashing with each other.

The one I have started using is for tooltips on text input fields that is initialised in the following way:

```
$("[title]").mbTooltip
```

What I would like to do is either only target the titles of text boxes or even those with of class `text`.

I tried this myself but couldn't get it to work and I haven't found anything on the web about how to do it either :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$(".text[title][title!=]")
```

This will select elements with the `text` class that have a non-empty `title` attribute

**working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/GdU7E/

---

Or this:

```
$("input:textbox[title][title!=]")
```

Which will select all textbox `input` elements with a non-empty `title` attribute

**working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/GdU7E/1/

Comment: thank you, got it to work using `(".text[title]").mbTooltip(`

Answer (score 1):

$('input[title][type="text"].text')

Text input with class 'text'

Answer (score 1):

If you add a class for those titles, or better yet, wrap em into a heading, you could do something like:

```
$(".text h1").mbTooltip
```

furthermore, as far as i know, the 'title' tag is only used to specify the title of the document and it is not be used as an element.

Comment: `[title]` selects any element with a title attribute

Comment: my bad, thought he meant he was using title tags in his html

Answer (score 1):

For all text boxes you can select:

```
$(':text')
```

for only text boxes with .text class

```
$(':text.text')
```

jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/tgejW/